# Can you activate charges of Warlock's Scepter and Gloves of Eldritch Mixture in same round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock

Warlock's scepter mentions:

> ... a warlock (or any other character capable of invoking an eldritch blast) can choose to spend charges from the scepter to increase the amount of damage his eldritch blast deals.

And Gloves of Eldritch Admixture:

> Spending 1 or more charges adds extra damage to the next eldritch blast you make before the end of your turn.

Given they are both swift action to activate, can warlock activate both items in same round and boost its eldritch blast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only perform a single swift action per turn.

[D20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#swiftActions)

Comment: I see. Is it not possible to convert a move action, free action or immediate action into swift action given character does not move? Or is there way to have 2 swift action in 1 round?

Comment: @UniQuadrion Ruby Knight Vindicator prc can do it (and probably more than 2). Unfortunately, it isn't related to Warlock in any way. Also, it is more or less reasonable to allow swift action in place of standart action (played like that, no isses noticed), but it is not RAW.